# Is there a non-analytic function $g$ such that $\exp(s g(z))$ is always analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, function-and-relation-composition, analytic-functions

Does there exist a complex function $g(z)$ that is *not* analytic on the unit disk, such that $\exp(s g(z))$ *is* analytic on the unit disk for all complex numbers $s$? What about for some continuous range of $s$ (e.g. all real numbers, or all positive numbers, or all $s \in [0,1]$)?

For example, if we only consider $s=1$, then $g(z) := \log(z)$ is not analytic on the unit disk, but $\exp(\log(z)) = z$ obviously is. But if we allow $s$ to vary, then $\exp(s \log(z)) = z^s$ is only analytic on the unit disk if $s$ is a natural number, so $g(z) = \log(z)$ doesn't work.

Comment: Note that your counterexample does not really work as $\log$ is not defined on all of the circle. However, one can indeed give counterexamples without the parameter $s$ as I do in my answer below.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I don't think it's an issue that $\log(z)$ is not defined on the whole unit disk; you can choose a branch and then assign values along the branch cut to be continuous with one side of the cut or the other. But you are correct that in that case $g(z)$ won't be continuous along the filled-in branch cut.

Comment: I am not worried about branches, but about the origin.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, contrary to my original believe, one really needs this additional parameter $s$ for the statement having a chance to be true. In fact $g$ being continuous would be enough.

**Example of non-analytic function if we consider only $s=1$:**

Without the condition with the parameter $s$ we have the counterexample
$$ g(z) = \begin{cases} 0,& z=0, \\ 2\pi i,& z \neq 0. \end{cases} $$

**Proof if we assume in addition to the conditions listed by the OP that** $g$ **is bounded or continuous:**

One can also show the following version

> Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set, $\varepsilon>0$ and $g: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ bounded or continuous such that $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, z \mapsto e^{sg(z)}$ is analytic for all $s\in (0;\varepsilon)$, then $g$ is analytic.

If $g$ is continuous and $g$ does not vanish anywhere, then we can write locally $g(\zeta) = \ln(e^{g(\zeta)})$ in a neighborhood of $z$, where $\ln$ is the branch of the logarithm that maps $e^{g(z)}$ to $g(z)$. As it is the composition of analytic functions, it is analytic. However, analyiticity is a local property, thus, $g$ is analytic.

Now if $g(z) = 0$, then we consider $h(w) :=g(w)+1$. Then we have $e^{h(w)} = e \cdot e^{g(w)}$, which is analytic and $h(z) =1$. Thus, $h$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $z$. Then clearly $g(w) = h(w) -1$ is analytic as well in a neighborhood of $z$. Therefore, if $g$ continuous we get that $g$ is analytic.

Next we want to show that if $g$ is assumed to be bounded, then the conditions of the OP force $g$ to be continuous as well. Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and pick any sequence $(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $z_n \rightarrow z$. Then we have (as $e^g$ is continuous)
$$ e^{g(z)} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{g(z_n)}.$$
Taking the absolute value, we get
$$ e^{\text{Re}(g(z))}=\vert e^{g(z)} \vert = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{\text{Re}(g(z_n))}. $$
As $\ln:(0;\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, we get
$$ \text{Re}(g(z)) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \text{Re}(g(z_n)).$$
Thus, we get
$$ e^{i\text{Im}(g(z))} = \frac{e^{g(z)}}{e^{\text{Re}(g(z))}} =
 \frac{ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{g(z_n)}}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{\text{Re}(g(z_n))}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{g(z_n)}}{e^{\text{Re}(g(z_n))}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{i\text{Im}(g(z_n))}.$$

Now the problem is to get rid of the potential differences of $2\pi$. If you assume that $g$ is bounded, then this is quite easy. Then we can pick subsequences, where $i \text{Im}(g(z_{n_k}))$ actually converges. If you have different limits (after removing the angle) $2\pi m$ and $2\pi \ell$, then we can just pick $s$ so small that $s2\pi m$ and $s2\pi \ell$ are both smaller than $2\pi$ and then they need to coincide. This means $g$ is continuous (as both $\text{Re}(g)$ and $\text{Im}(g)$ are continuous) and hence by a previous argument $g$ is also analytic.

**Replacing boundedness with more parameters:**

In order to conclude that $g$ is analytic without continuity/boundedness of $g$, one needs to handle the case, when $g$ blows up. We can handle this case if we can choose the parameter $s$ in a slightly larger set:

> Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set, $\varepsilon>0$ and $g: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, z \mapsto e^{sg(z)}$ is analytic for all $s\in B(0;\varepsilon)=\{ z\in \mathbb{C} \ : \ \vert z \vert <\varepsilon \}$, then $g$ is analytic.

Let us define

$$ G: \Omega \times B(0;\varepsilon) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, (z,s) \mapsto e^{sg(z)}. $$

First let us note that $G$ is separately holomorphic and hence by Hartogs' theorem $G$ is continuous. Let $z_0\in \Omega$, we just want to show that in a neighborhood of $z_0$ the function $g$ is bounded, then we are done by the argument we gave above.

Let us fix some closed ball $B=\overline{B(z_0, \eta)} \subset \Omega$ (where $\eta>0$). Assume by contradiction that $g$ is not bounded on $B$. Then there exists a sequence $(\zeta_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq B$ such that $\vert g(\zeta_n) \vert \rightarrow \infty$. As $B$ is compact, we can assume wlog that $\zeta_n \rightarrow \zeta$ for some $\zeta \in B$. However, then we get the contradiction

$$ 1 = e^0 = G(\zeta, 0) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} G(\zeta_n, \frac{1}{\vert g(\zeta_n) \vert})= e^1 =e. $$

Comment: I don't think we can legitimately say that $g$ is globally analytic just because we can locally choose branches that make it locally analytic. Wouldn't that same reasoning imply that $\log(z)$ itself was analytic away from its branch point? I think you could run into monodromy issues as you try to continue around branch points.

Comment: @tparker That is not an issue. The difference is that we start from a given function $g$ and represent it in terms of analytic functions. I am not defining the function $g$ using any branches, only check its analyticity by solving locally.

Comment: @tparker To be more precise, the reason why I do not run into any troubles is because continuity allows me to choose a branch for a whole neighborhood. This is exactly what fails for $\log$, the discontinuity does not allow you to pick a single branch for a neighborhood of a point in the branch cut.

Comment: Suppose we start with the standard branch of log with the branch cut along the negative real axis, and we apply this branch to $e^{g(z)}$. Then we get an analytic result except along the curves where $Im(g(z))$ is an odd multiple of $i \pi$ so that $\exp(g(z))$ is negative. It’s true that near those curves we can choose a different branch of log, but how do we know that the values will agree as we approach the curves from different sides? I agree that $\log(\exp(g(z)))$ will be analytic, but I worry that it might be defined on a Riemannian surface more complicated than the unit disk.

Comment: Also, respectfully, would you mind editing your answer to make it clearer and grammatically correct? I genuinely can’t understand exactly what you’re trying to say, because I think you may be missing a “not” in your second paragraph and an $i$ in your third. And I don’t understand which is the “statement” of mine that you’re referring to or what you mean by “such a function”. Thanks.

Comment: Where am I missing a "not" or an "i"?

Comment: Ok, let's do this once more. You start with $\text{Log}$ that is the principal part of the logarithm with branch cut along the negative reals. Then we have a jump along this cut (pick whichever part you want for the cut). Then (forgetting the origin) we have $e^{\text{Log}(z)}=z$ which is analytic. Now, where does my argument break down for this example? Well, pick $z=-1/2$, so on the cut. Then we would like to pick a branch of the logarithm $\ln$ such that $\text{Log}(z)=\log(e^{\text{Log}(z)})$ for a whole neighborhood of $z=-1/2$.

Comment: This you cannot do. However, if $g$ is continuous you can clearly pick a branch $\ln$ such that $g(z)=\ln(e^{g(z)})$. I do not understand what you mean by "I agree that $\log(e^{g(z)}))$ will be analytic, but I worry that it might be defined on a Riemannian surface...". We have not altered the function $g$, in particular we have not changed its domain of definition.

Comment: Okay after your clarification I now understand what you are getting at. I believe the missing $i$ is in your explicit counterexample in the $s=1$ case, because $e^{2\pi} \neq e^0$ but $e^{2\pi i} = e^0$. But I was mostly concerned with the case where $g$ blows up and is discontinuous so you really do need to use $s$, as in my example $g(z) = \log(z)$.

Comment: @tparker Yes, that is the interesting case. Given that you want to be very precise. If you take $g(z)=\log(z)$ (your favourite choice of branch), you cannot make $e^{g(z)}$ continuous at the origin, no matter what you choose for $g(0)$. That is because the exponential does not have any zeros. Would you mind sharing how you came up with this fun question (I am curious what triggered this)?

Comment: @tparker I can now do the case where $g$ is unbounded. Check my updated answer.